# How to add additional navigational properties that won't be persisted?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

public enum ItemType
{
    Customer, Organization, Department, //etc
}
```

The `ItemId` is a foreignkey to a separate model/table. The above model maps as-is with the underlying table.

Now I would like to automatically load the related entities when loading an `Order`.

Is this possible by using composite foreign keys when mapping, as in:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public ItemTypeCustomer => ItemType.Customer;
    public ItemTypeOrganization => ItemType.Organization;
    public ItemTypeDeparment => ItemType.Department;
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
   .HasOptional(p => p.Customer)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.ItemTypeCustomer , p.ItemId });
```

Would the above work? Is it even possible to build something like this using code-first?

Comment: Do you just need to get values from table with some related data?

Comment: @picolino Yes. And I'm trying to avoid using a view or sp and then map the properties manually.

Comment: The longer I look at this the lesser I understand what you want. That's mainly because you show two `Order` classes and the rest of the code is tentative, almost pseudo-code.

Answer (score -1):

`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public IEnumerable GetCandidates() { return context.Orders.Include(C=> C.ItemType); }'